# Can `ejabberd` be installed without plenty of dependencies on fedora?

Tags: fedora, package-management, erlang, ejabberd

I installed the server edition of fedora 35 (no DE) recently and now I'm about to set-up an xmpp server. Therefore I want to install `ejabberd`. However, I noticed that it pulls in a lot of dependencies:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 2:01:16 ago on Sat 20 Nov 2021 05:03:37 PM CET.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                            Arch   Version                Repo     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 ejabberd                           noarch 20.07-5.fc35           fedora  5.3 M
Installing dependencies:
 SDL2                               x86_64 2.0.16-4.fc35          updates 535 k
 adobe-mappings-cmap                noarch 20190730-1.fc35        updates 2.1 M
 adobe-mappings-cmap-deprecated     noarch 20190730-1.fc35        updates 105 k
 adobe-mappings-pdf                 noarch 20180407-9.fc35        fedora  637 k
 adwaita-cursor-theme               noarch 41.0-1.fc35            fedora  625 k
 adwaita-icon-theme                 noarch 41.0-1.fc35            fedora   11 M
 at-spi2-atk                        x86_64 2.38.0-3.fc35          fedora   86 k
 at-spi2-core                       x86_64 2.42.0-1.fc35          fedora  176 k
 atk                                x86_64 2.36.0-4.fc35          fedora  269 k
 avahi-glib                         x86_64 0.8-14.fc35            fedora   15 k
 bluez-libs                         x86_64 5.62-2.fc35            updates  84 k
 bubblewrap                         x86_64 0.5.0-1.fc35           fedora   53 k
 cairo                              x86_64 1.17.4-4.fc35          fedora  664 k
 cairo-gobject                      x86_64 1.17.4-4.fc35          fedora   18 k
 cdparanoia-libs                    x86_64 10.2-38.fc35           fedora   53 k
 colord-libs                        x86_64 1.4.5-3.fc35           fedora  232 k
 double-conversion                  x86_64 3.1.5-5.fc35           fedora   48 k
 ejabberd-selinux                   noarch 20.07-5.fc35           fedora   20 k
 elixir                             x86_64 1.12.3-3.fc35          updates 5.6 M
 erlang-asn1                        x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 901 k
 erlang-base64url                   noarch 1.0.1-6.fc35           fedora   12 k
 erlang-cache_tab                   x86_64 1.0.25-3.fc35          fedora   65 k
 erlang-compiler                    x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 1.9 M
 erlang-crypto                      x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 174 k
 erlang-dialyzer                    x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 1.2 M
 erlang-edoc                        x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 411 k
 erlang-eimp                        x86_64 1.0.17-3.fc35          fedora   42 k
 erlang-epam                        x86_64 1.0.9-3.fc35           fedora   23 k
 erlang-erts                        x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 2.7 M
 erlang-esip                        x86_64 1.0.37-3.fc35          fedora  186 k
 erlang-eunit                       x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 174 k
 erlang-ezlib                       x86_64 1.0.8-3.fc35           fedora   22 k
 erlang-fast_tls                    x86_64 1.1.8-3.fc35           fedora   56 k
 erlang-fast_xml                    x86_64 1.1.43-4.fc35          fedora  195 k
 erlang-fast_yaml                   x86_64 1.0.27-3.fc35          fedora   29 k
 erlang-idna                        noarch 6.0.1-3.fc35           fedora  702 k
 erlang-inets                       x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 673 k
 erlang-jiffy                       x86_64 1.0.5-3.fc35           fedora   46 k
 erlang-jose                        noarch 1.10.1-6.fc35          fedora  727 k
 erlang-kernel                      x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 1.9 M
 erlang-luerl                       noarch 0.3-8.fc35             fedora  457 k
 erlang-mnesia                      x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 903 k
 erlang-mqtree                      x86_64 1.0.10-3.fc35          fedora   30 k
 erlang-odbc                        x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates  66 k
 erlang-os_mon                      x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 107 k
 erlang-p1_acme                     noarch 1.0.8-3.fc35           fedora   69 k
 erlang-p1_mysql                    noarch 1.0.16-3.fc35          fedora   64 k
 erlang-p1_oauth2                   noarch 0.6.7-3.fc35           fedora   39 k
 erlang-p1_pgsql                    noarch 1.1.10-3.fc35          fedora   60 k
 erlang-p1_utils                    noarch 1.0.20-3.fc35          fedora  179 k
 erlang-parsetools                  x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 210 k
 erlang-pkix                        noarch 1.0.6-3.fc35           fedora   72 k
 erlang-public_key                  x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 806 k
 erlang-runtime_tools               x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 250 k
 erlang-sasl                        x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 324 k
 erlang-sd_notify                   noarch 1.1-3.fc35             fedora   13 k
 erlang-snmp                        x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 2.0 M
 erlang-ssl                         x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 1.6 M
 erlang-stdlib                      x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 3.8 M
 erlang-stringprep                  x86_64 1.0.22-3.fc35          fedora   48 k
 erlang-stun                        noarch 1.0.37-3.fc35          fedora  144 k
 erlang-syntax_tools                x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 343 k
 erlang-tools                       x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 712 k
 erlang-unicode_util_compat         noarch 0.5.0-5.fc35           fedora   83 k
 erlang-wx                          x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 4.9 M
 erlang-xmerl                       x86_64 24.1.4-1.fc35          updates 1.3 M
 erlang-xmpp                        x86_64 1.4.9-3.fc35           fedora  1.9 M
 erlang-yconf                       noarch 1.0.7-3.fc35           fedora   58 k
 exempi                             x86_64 2.5.1-7.fc35           fedora  515 k
 exiv2-libs                         x86_64 0.27.5-1.fc35          updates 777 k
 fdk-aac-free                       x86_64 2.0.0-7.fc35           fedora  324 k
 flac-libs                          x86_64 1.3.3-9.fc35           fedora  218 k
 flatpak-selinux                    noarch 1.12.2-1.fc35          updates  22 k
 flatpak-session-helper             x86_64 1.12.2-1.fc35          updates  44 k
 fuse                               x86_64 2.9.9-13.fc35          fedora   78 k
 gdk-pixbuf2-modules                x86_64 2.42.6-2.fc35          fedora   84 k
 giflib                             x86_64 5.2.1-8.fc35           fedora   47 k
 google-droid-sans-fonts            noarch 20200215-10.fc35       fedora  2.7 M
 graphene                           x86_64 1.10.6-3.fc35          fedora   64 k
 graphviz                           x86_64 2.48.0-3.fc35          fedora  1.4 M
 gsm                                x86_64 1.0.19-6.fc35          fedora   33 k
 gstreamer1                         x86_64 1.19.3-1.fc35          updates 1.4 M
 gstreamer1-plugins-base            x86_64 1.19.3-1.fc35          updates 2.1 M
 gtk-update-icon-cache              x86_64 3.24.30-4.fc35         fedora   35 k
 gtk2                               x86_64 2.24.33-5.fc35         fedora  3.5 M
 gtk3                               x86_64 3.24.30-4.fc35         fedora  4.8 M
 gts                                x86_64 0.7.6-40.20121130.fc35 fedora  233 k
 harfbuzz-icu                       x86_64 2.8.2-2.fc35           fedora   15 k
 hicolor-icon-theme                 noarch 0.17-11.fc35           fedora   44 k
 hyphen                             x86_64 2.8.8-16.fc35          fedora   29 k
 iso-codes                          noarch 4.6.0-2.fc35           fedora  3.3 M
 jbig2dec-libs                      x86_64 0.19-5.fc35            fedora   73 k
 lame-libs                          x86_64 3.100-11.fc35          fedora  333 k
 lasi                               x86_64 1.1.3-7.fc35           fedora   55 k
 lcms2                              x86_64 2.12-2.fc35            fedora  167 k
 libICE                             x86_64 1.0.10-7.fc35          fedora   70 k
 libSM                              x86_64 1.2.3-9.fc35           fedora   41 k
 libX11-xcb                         x86_64 1.7.2-3.fc35           fedora   11 k
 libXaw                             x86_64 1.0.13-18.fc35         fedora  196 k
 libXcomposite                      x86_64 0.4.5-6.fc35           fedora   23 k
 libXcursor                         x86_64 1.2.0-6.fc35           fedora   30 k
 libXdamage                         x86_64 1.1.5-6.fc35           fedora   22 k
 libXext                            x86_64 1.3.4-7.fc35           fedora   39 k
 libXfixes                          x86_64 6.0.0-2.fc35           fedora   19 k
 libXft                             x86_64 2.3.3-7.fc35           fedora   61 k
 libXi                              x86_64 1.7.10-7.fc35          fedora   38 k
 libXinerama                        x86_64 1.1.4-9.fc35           fedora   14 k
 libXmu                             x86_64 1.1.3-7.fc35           fedora   74 k
 libXrandr                          x86_64 1.5.2-7.fc35           fedora   27 k
 libXrender                         x86_64 0.9.10-15.fc35         fedora   27 k
 libXt                              x86_64 1.2.0-5.fc35           fedora  179 k
 libXtst                            x86_64 1.2.3-15.fc35          fedora   20 k
 libXv                              x86_64 1.0.11-15.fc35         fedora   18 k
 libXxf86vm                         x86_64 1.1.4-17.fc35          fedora   18 k
 libasyncns                         x86_64 0.8-21.fc35            fedora   30 k
 libcanberra                        x86_64 0.30-26.fc35           fedora   85 k
 libcloudproviders                  x86_64 0.3.1-4.fc35           fedora   45 k
 libcue                             x86_64 2.2.1-8.fc35           fedora   34 k
 libdatrie                          x86_64 0.2.13-2.fc35          fedora   32 k
 libdecor                           x86_64 0.1.0-1.fc35           fedora   40 k
 libdrm                             x86_64 2.4.107-2.fc35         fedora  162 k
 libepoxy                           x86_64 1.5.9-1.fc35           fedora  242 k
 libevdev                           x86_64 1.12.0-1.fc35          updates  45 k
 libexif                            x86_64 0.6.23-1.fc35          fedora  441 k
 libfontenc                         x86_64 1.1.3-16.fc35          fedora   30 k
 libgexiv2                          x86_64 0.14.0-1.fc35          fedora   95 k
 libglvnd                           x86_64 1:1.3.4-2.fc35         updates 135 k
 libglvnd-egl                       x86_64 1:1.3.4-2.fc35         updates  37 k
 libglvnd-glx                       x86_64 1:1.3.4-2.fc35         updates 144 k
 libgrss                            x86_64 0.7.0-13.fc35          fedora   63 k
 libgs                              x86_64 9.55.0-1.fc35          updates 3.5 M
 libgsf                             x86_64 1.14.47-4.fc35         fedora  245 k
 libgxps                            x86_64 0.3.2-2.fc35           fedora   78 k
 libijs                             x86_64 0.35-14.fc35           fedora   29 k
 libimobiledevice                   x86_64 1.3.0-4.fc35           fedora   75 k
 libiptcdata                        x86_64 1.0.5-9.fc35           fedora   61 k
 libldac                            x86_64 2.0.2.3-9.fc35         fedora   40 k
 libmanette                         x86_64 0.2.6-3.fc35           fedora   49 k
 libmspack                          x86_64 0.10.1-0.6.alpha.fc35  fedora   68 k
 libnotify                          x86_64 0.7.9-5.fc35           fedora   42 k
 libogg                             x86_64 2:1.3.5-2.fc35         fedora   33 k
 libosinfo                          x86_64 1.9.0-2.fc35           fedora  295 k
 libpaper                           x86_64 1.1.28-3.fc35          fedora   40 k
 libpciaccess                       x86_64 0.16-5.fc35            fedora   27 k
 libplist                           x86_64 2.2.0-5.fc35           fedora   76 k
 librsvg2                           x86_64 2.52.4-1.fc35          updates 3.6 M
 libsbc                             x86_64 1.5-2.fc35             fedora   47 k
 libshout                           x86_64 2.4.3-4.fc35           fedora   66 k
 libsndfile                         x86_64 1.0.31-5.fc35.fc35     fedora  206 k
 libthai                            x86_64 0.1.28-7.fc35          fedora  208 k
 libtheora                          x86_64 1:1.1.1-30.fc35        fedora  163 k
 libtracker-sparql                  x86_64 3.2.1-1.fc35           updates 351 k
 libusbmuxd                         x86_64 2.0.2-5.fc35           fedora   38 k
 libv4l                             x86_64 1.20.0-4.fc35          fedora  198 k
 libvisual                          x86_64 1:0.4.0-33.fc35        fedora  142 k
 libvorbis                          x86_64 1:1.3.7-4.fc35         fedora  192 k
 libvpx                             x86_64 1.10.0-2.fc35          fedora  1.0 M
 libwayland-client                  x86_64 1.19.0-2.fc35          fedora   32 k
 libwayland-cursor                  x86_64 1.19.0-2.fc35          fedora   19 k
 libwayland-egl                     x86_64 1.19.0-2.fc35          fedora   12 k
 libwayland-server                  x86_64 1.19.0-2.fc35          fedora   40 k
 libwpe                             x86_64 1.10.1-2.fc35          fedora   27 k
 libxshmfence                       x86_64 1.3-9.fc35             fedora   12 k
 lksctp-tools                       x86_64 1.0.18-11.fc35         fedora   91 k
 llvm-libs                          x86_64 13.0.0-4.fc35          updates  25 M
 low-memory-monitor                 x86_64 2.1-4.fc35             fedora   35 k
 mesa-libEGL                        x86_64 21.2.5-2.fc35          updates 120 k
 mesa-libGL                         x86_64 21.2.5-2.fc35          updates 170 k
 mesa-libGLU                        x86_64 9.0.1-5.fc35           fedora  147 k
 mesa-libgbm                        x86_64 21.2.5-2.fc35          updates  43 k
 mesa-libglapi                      x86_64 21.2.5-2.fc35          updates  54 k
 mesa-vulkan-drivers                x86_64 21.2.5-2.fc35          updates 5.0 M
 mkfontscale                        x86_64 1.2.1-3.fc35           fedora   31 k
 mpg123-libs                        x86_64 1.26.5-2.fc35          fedora  312 k
 netpbm                             x86_64 10.96.00-1.fc35        updates 185 k
 openjpeg2                          x86_64 2.4.0-4.fc35           fedora  163 k
 opus                               x86_64 1.3.1-9.fc35           fedora  200 k
 orc                                x86_64 0.4.31-5.fc35          fedora  182 k
 osinfo-db                          noarch 20211013-1.fc35        updates 247 k
 osinfo-db-tools                    x86_64 1.9.0-2.fc35           fedora   66 k
 ostree-libs                        x86_64 2021.5-2.fc35          updates 420 k
 pango                              x86_64 1.49.3-1.fc35          updates 313 k
 pipewire-libs                      x86_64 0.3.40-1.fc35          updates 1.4 M
 poppler                            x86_64 21.08.0-1.fc35         fedora  1.1 M
 poppler-data                       noarch 0.4.9-8.fc35           fedora  1.8 M
 poppler-glib                       x86_64 21.08.0-1.fc35         fedora  155 k
 pulseaudio-libs                    x86_64 15.0-2.fc35            fedora  666 k
 rtkit                              x86_64 0.11-28.fc35           fedora   55 k
 sound-theme-freedesktop            noarch 0.8-16.fc35            fedora  377 k
 speex                              x86_64 1.2.0-9.fc35           fedora   67 k
 taglib                             x86_64 1.12-5.fc35            fedora  344 k
 totem-pl-parser                    x86_64 3.26.6-3.fc35          fedora  131 k
 twolame-libs                       x86_64 0.3.13-18.fc35         fedora   57 k
 uchardet                           x86_64 0.0.6-14.fc35          fedora   94 k
 unixODBC                           x86_64 2.3.9-4.fc35           fedora  456 k
 upower                             x86_64 0.99.13-1.fc35         fedora  167 k
 urw-base35-bookman-fonts           noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora  846 k
 urw-base35-c059-fonts              noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora  874 k
 urw-base35-d050000l-fonts          noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora   76 k
 urw-base35-fonts                   noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora   10 k
 urw-base35-fonts-common            noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora   21 k
 urw-base35-gothic-fonts            noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora  643 k
 urw-base35-nimbus-mono-ps-fonts    noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora  795 k
 urw-base35-nimbus-roman-fonts      noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora  856 k
 urw-base35-nimbus-sans-fonts       noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora  1.3 M
 urw-base35-p052-fonts              noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora  973 k
 urw-base35-standard-symbols-ps-fonts
                                    noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora   42 k
 urw-base35-z003-fonts              noarch 20200910-9.fc35        fedora  276 k
 vulkan-loader                      x86_64 1.2.189.0-1.fc35       fedora  122 k
 wavpack                            x86_64 5.4.0-3.fc35           fedora  212 k
 webkit2gtk3                        x86_64 2.34.1-2.fc35          updates  14 M
 webkit2gtk3-jsc                    x86_64 2.34.1-2.fc35          updates 6.2 M
 webrtc-audio-processing            x86_64 0.3.1-7.fc35           fedora  305 k
 wireplumber                        x86_64 0.4.5-1.fc35           updates  68 k
 wireplumber-libs                   x86_64 0.4.5-1.fc35           updates 300 k
 woff2                              x86_64 1.0.2-13.fc35          fedora   61 k
 wpebackend-fdo                     x86_64 1.10.0-2.fc35          fedora   44 k
 wxBase3                            x86_64 3.0.5.1-5.fc35         fedora  991 k
 wxGTK3                             x86_64 3.0.5.1-5.fc35         fedora  4.4 M
 wxGTK3-gl                          x86_64 3.0.5.1-5.fc35         fedora   37 k
 wxGTK3-i18n                        noarch 3.0.5.1-5.fc35         fedora  492 k
 wxGTK3-webview                     x86_64 3.0.5.1-5.fc35         fedora   60 k
 xdg-dbus-proxy                     x86_64 0.1.2-5.fc35           fedora   41 k
 xdg-desktop-portal                 x86_64 1.10.1-2.fc35          updates 355 k
 xorg-x11-fonts-ISO8859-1-100dpi    noarch 7.5-32.fc35            fedora  1.0 M
Installing weak dependencies:
 dconf                              x86_64 0.40.0-5.fc35          fedora  108 k
 exiv2                              x86_64 0.27.5-1.fc35          updates 976 k
 flatpak                            x86_64 1.12.2-1.fc35          updates 1.5 M
 geoclue2                           x86_64 2.5.7-6.fc35           fedora  114 k
 gstreamer1-plugins-good            x86_64 1.19.3-1.fc35          updates 2.1 M
 libcanberra-gtk2                   x86_64 0.30-26.fc35           fedora   25 k
 libcanberra-gtk3                   x86_64 0.30-26.fc35           fedora   31 k
 p11-kit-server                     x86_64 0.23.22-4.fc35         fedora  190 k
 pipewire                           x86_64 0.3.40-1.fc35          updates  38 k
 pipewire-alsa                      x86_64 0.3.40-1.fc35          updates  62 k
 pipewire-jack-audio-connection-kit x86_64 0.3.40-1.fc35          updates 129 k
 pipewire-pulseaudio                x86_64 0.3.40-1.fc35          updates  27 k
 tracker                            x86_64 3.2.1-1.fc35           updates 532 k
 tracker-miners                     x86_64 3.2.1-1.fc35           updates 875 k
 xdg-desktop-portal-gtk             x86_64 1.10.0-2.fc35          updates 132 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  241 Packages

Total download size: 177 M
Installed size: 556 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Is it possible to install ejabberd without all the dependencies that are ment for GUI applications, like `libwayland`, `gtk`, `adwaita-icon-theme`, ...

Any hints?

Comment: The title seems to be asking a theoretical question ("why...") but the body of the text seems to be asking a more practical question, although I can't really tell what that practical question might be. (How to disable dependencies?  How to determine what dependencies are safe to disable?) Could help me understand what the actual question is?

Comment: I tried to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 6):

The [`erlang`](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/erlang) package contains all the standard Erlang libraries. This includes the [`wx`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/wx/index.html) GUI library, which is in the [`erlang-wx`](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=28214959) package. That package pulls in the native wxWidgets library which pulls in Gtk and many other GUI libraries. You aren't getting a local GUI though (no Xorg or Wayland server), just the ability to run GUI applications displayed remotely.

The [`ejabberd`](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=27480613) package does *not* declare a dependency on `erlang`. It depends on various Erlang libraries related mostly to networking and to various file formats. I don't understand how the `erlang` package would get pulled in. I can't find a package that requires or suggests it. It looks like you're explicitly asking for `erlang` to be installed. In which case, well, just don't.

Comment: You are right, the output above is produced by `dnf install erlang`. However, ejabberd also requires installing `erlang-wx`. So it seems there is no way around installing all these GUI related packages.